# Open text files with different names-Python

Tags: python

I have a python code which opens a text file read and do some processes. The input text file has to be updated each day with a new one. Currently I use following code to open the file.

```
f = open('sample20130616.txt','r')
```

But in this method some one has to go inside the code and modify the file name(Since the file names are not unique).

What is the proper method to handle this?

Comment: I would use a file name auto-generated from the current date or take the file name as an input parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the filename as parameter when you call your application:

```
python myapp.py file.txt
```

Then in your code:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    f = open(filename)
```

Comment: Could you please explain this?

Comment: When you execute your application you specify what file you want to read/write without having to modify your code. This code gets the name of the file when you launch your script

Comment: Thanks Very much...Working..:)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily generate the current date and hence your filename with the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

filename = 'sample{0}{1:02d}{2:02d}.txt'.format(today.year, today.month, today.day)
f = open(filename,'r')
```

Comment: Sure, but then it doesn't automatically generate the file's name. You'll have each day to write your file's name (which makes it easier to use, but still require the user to know how things are coded) + If you want to do a script that automates this operation you'll still have to somehow generate the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in time function!

```
    from time import gmtime, strftime
    fname='sample'+strftime("%Y%m%d", gmtime())+'.txt'
    f = open(fname,'r')
```

Comment: Beware: with this solution months (1-9) will be formated to '6' instead of '06', so the filename will be incorrect. Check my answer which adds leading zeros with the formating options.